# how to display MLM data in treeview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, mlm

[MLM data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2LcO.jpg)

i have multilevel marketing software data in which a person may join many other person and again joind person will do the same.

i have tried these code

```
     protected void load_data()
         {

        strQuery = "select * from redjoining where id=995";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        dt = dbcon.GetData(cmd);

        string cat_code = dt.Rows[0]["id"].ToString();
        string cat_name = dt.Rows[0]["userName"].ToString();

        TreeNode parent = new TreeNode();
        parent.Value = cat_code;
        parent.Text = cat_name;
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(parent);
        add_childs(parent, cat_code);

    }
```

now to add child node i use this code but it add only top single record only.

```
  protected void add_childs(TreeNode tn, string category_code) 
  {

        strQuery = "select * from redjoining where sponserid=@category_code";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_code", category_code);
        dt = dbcon.GetData(cmd);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string cat_code = dt.Rows[0]["id"].ToString();
            string cat_name = dt.Rows[0]["userName"].ToString();

            TreeNode child = new TreeNode();
            child.Value = cat_code;
            child.Text = cat_name;
            tn.ChildNodes.Add(child);

            add_childs(child, cat_code); //calling the same function
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you update the question with what you WANT to happen? So far as I can see, there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your method to add child records in treeview, check below code

```
protected void add_childs(TreeNode tn, string category_code) 
  {

        strQuery = "select * from redjoining where sponserid=@category_code";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_code", category_code);
        dt = dbcon.GetData(cmd);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string cat_code = dt.Rows[i]["id"].ToString();
            string cat_name = dt.Rows[i]["userName"].ToString();

            TreeNode child = new TreeNode();
            child.Value = cat_code;
            child.Text = cat_name;
            tn.ChildNodes.Add(child);

            add_childs(child, cat_code); //calling the same function
        }
    }
```

In your code you always using `dt.Rows[0]["id"].ToString()`

use i as your dt have multiple records and you are iterating for loop.

Hope this will help.

Comment: either use i or 0 in dt.Rows[0]["id"].ToString() it add only first record, because add_childs(child, cat_code);  jump from for loop.

Comment: In that case, you need to write a sql query to get all parent and n-level child records. Search for nested CTE for this it will be helpful for you.